# ErrorSessionTokenFilter: Token provided via HTTP Header does not match the token generated by the server

Tags: powershell, rest, api

I am trying to extract Event information from Viptela using its API interface. I managed to get alert and token information but when I tried to extract Event information, it gave me an HTML login page instead of JSON with event information.

I came to know that before accessing the Event API link I should have the token to call Event API URL. I am not sure which step I have missed and it is not working for me. Could someone point out the missing piece from the code below to rectify the issue?

```
    if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'TrustAllCertsPolicy').Type) {
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
        using System.Net;
        using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
        public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
            public bool CheckValidationResult(
                ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
                WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
                return true;
            }
        }
"@
}
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$Authorization = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
    [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(
        (
            "{0}:{1}" -f ('UserName' , 'Password')
        )
    )
)

$Headers = @{"authorization" = "Basic "+$Authorization}


$Uri = "https://vmanage.viptela.net:443/dataservice/client/token"
$gettoken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers -SessionVariable websession
$gettoken.Cookies
$cookie = ($websession.Cookies.GetCookies($Uri)).Value

$body = '{
    "query": {
        "condition": "AND",
        "rules": [
            {
                "value": [
                    "1"
                ],
                "field": "entry_time",
                "type": "date",
                "operator": "last_n_hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}'

$Headersnew = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$Headersnew.Add("X-XSRF-TOKEN", $gettoken)
$Headersnew.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+$Authorization)
$Headersnew.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$Headersnew.Add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+$cookie)


$geteventurl = "https://vmanage.viptela.net:443/dataservice/event"

$getevent = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $geteventurl -body $body -Headers $Headersnew 
$getevent
```

The result I got is given below, I tried the same via PostMan it works fine.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : ErrorSessionTokenFilter: Token provided via HTTP Header does not match the token generated by the server.
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\00viptela\GetEvents.ps1:58 char:13
+ $getevent = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $geteventurl -body $b ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Please help.

Regards,
Naresh

Comment: Via PostMan it works fine when I used Powershell it throws an error.
Invoke-RestMethod : ErrorSessionTokenFilter: Token provided via HTTP Header does not match the token generated by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, This might help someone who may have a similar issue.

In the first Request add a -SessionVariable parameter and give it a string
(any string without the preceding $) then in second Request pass that string 
(this time with a preceding $) to the -WebSession parameter.

After adding the -websession parameter to the second call then it worked. (-WebSession $websession)

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $geteventurl -body $body -Headers $Headersnew -WebSession $websession
```

Hope it helps others.

Regards,
Naresh